# Having trouble putting icon inside input box

Tags: html, css, textbox, icons

I'm having trouble adding this icon inside my input box (on the left side). So far I have it so it looks as if it is inside the box, which is exactly what I want. The problem I'm having is when I type inside it, the text goes on top of the icon. How can I fix this? I tried adding padding to the right of it, but it did not work...

```
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

#icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 75px;
}

.inputBox {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 9px !important;
}


    <div class="wrapper">
          <i id="icon" class="uk-icon-credit-card uk-icon-small"></i>
          <input style="width: 250px;" class="uk-form-large uk-text-center inputBox" type="text" name="cardNumber" placeholder="Card Number">
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see where in your code you are adding the icon.

Comment: It is in the HTML, above the <input>

Comment: No, this is an italicized element with an id and some classes. No where are you specifying what the name of the icon is.

Comment: I am following Uikit http://getuikit.com/docs/icon.html look at the example of how they include their icons

Comment: Oh, I see. It is using other CSS files to add the icon.

Comment: Did you try removing the code I suggested?

Comment: yes but then the icon was outside of the input box. I think I fixed it though, I needed padding after all

Comment: Great. Also, it's okay if it's outside of the input box, you could always remove the border from the input box and place the border around the wrapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown all your code, but from what I can see if you remove all the styling from your `#icon` it should work. This way it's flowing inline with the input element and should position itself next to it. In other words, do not use `position: absolute` here as absolute will remove the icon from the normal flow of the document. So remove this from your CSS:

```
#icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 75px;
}
```